# project raised exception class abstract error with message "Abstract Error'

Tags: delphi

I have parent class TPerDevice which has Virtual abstarct method "doAction" , and child class TPerPrnDevice which override "doAction"
does any body know why is i got abstarct exception ?
Thanks 
["Abstract Error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpZbh.png)

```
type
  TPerDevice = class(TThread)
  public
    function    doAction(oPrm:String):String; virtual; abstract;
  end;

type 
  TPerPrnDevice = class(TPerDevice)
  public
    //function    doAction(oPrm:String):String;
  end;

type
  TxchPrn = class(TPerPrnDevice)
    function    doAction(oPrm:String):String;override;
    procedure   doLocalJob(oPrm:String);
  end;

...

function TxchPrn.doAction(oPrm: String): String;
begin
     doLocalJob(oPrm);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR Devices: array of TPerDevice;
begin
    SetLength(Devices,2);
    Devices[0]:=TxchPrn.Create;
    Devices[0].doAction('Print');
end;

procedure TxchPrn.doLocalJob(oPrm: String);
begin
 ShowMessage(oPrm);
end;
```

Comment: You have a thread which doesn't even have an `Execute` procedure. You will have to override the `Execute` procedure and implement it. As to why you don't have one, and how you expect anything to work, I don't know, because you've only shown us little bits and pieces of your code.

Comment: The code is a total mess. Can't you format it so that it is clear? You have much bigger problems though. Your understanding of how threads work is broken badly.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to implement thread execution method [**Execute**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Execute).